Framer motion - animate path with progress tied to scroll, not to path length
I have a vertical stepper with steps on left, right, left, right, etc... In center there's a motion.path which is a vertical line with slight curves leaning toward each step. This path should be animated (drawn) as I scroll and it should be drawn some amount from the bottom of screen eg 100px. However I have a minor problem. Distance between line and bottom of the screen varies, which is due to the line being not entirely straight.
Question: Can I make it fill the path "vertically", so that even if path being 2000px long, which has 1500px in first half and only 500px in the other, when the scroll is 50%, then those 1500px are filled, not 1000px?
Here's the picture showing the problem, I have 5 steps, so the 4th one should be ideally at 75%, however 75% is a bit further.

